# Visual Studio Code Stopped Running Python Scripts - Seems to Run Batch File Instead

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I click "Debug-Start Without Debugging", Visual Studio Code has stopped running scripts.  It has been working fine for months, but stopped recently.  Even this simple Python script won't run in VS Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0,1], [0,1])
plt.show()
```

As output I get:

```
PS C:\EV_Analytics> & cmd /k "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate.bat 
& powershell"
C:\EV_Analytics>python C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\etc\keras\load_config.py  
1>temp.txt
C:\EV_Analytics>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt
C:\EV_Analytics>del temp.txt
C:\EV_Analytics>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
C:\EV_Analytics>if errorlevel 1 (
ver  1>nul
set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
)
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Also, the debugger starts but times out with a popup that says "Timeout waiting for debugger connection".

I am running on Windows 10. VS Code is 1.27.2.  Python is 3.6.4 (Anaconda3 5.1.0).  The output references Keras/Theano but I have not run these in weeks on this machine.

Note that if I run a script from Spyder or the command line it works fine.  Only in VS Code do I get the problem.  There does not appear to be any obvious issue in launch.json. How do I get VS Code running Python again?

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same situation just a few hours ago and I found that if I change the flag "console" in your launch.json file to "none" the debugger just starts to work. I don't really know what is the cause of the issue but this workaround worked for me. Hope it helps to you too.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  It worked once, then the problem reappeared and now it seems stuck in the problem again.  Also printed output went to the debug console instead of the terminal which was not ideal.

Comment: Hi Again Kevin, it seems that is a bug of the python extension, I found this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2732. As you can read there are two solutions, one is to change your default terminal to cmd or disable the auto-activation of the terminal adding the following setting to your settings.json: "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false

Comment: Thanks Julio.  You have been a lot of help.  I wound up going back to PyCharm since they have fixed their issue of the difficulty of linking in the Anaconda libraries.  I will take another look at VS Code when they fix the bug.